# React horizontall button scroll

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a horizontal slider with buttons, but I have a problem with navigation.
When I click right and then left, the block moves 1 to the right.

i tried useEffect but then after refreshing the page the effect moves the whole page to the slider

my code:

```
const item = useRef({})
// use state
const lastIndex = slides.length;
// const lastIndex = slider_info.slice(-1);
const [i, setCount] = useState(0);

const scrollToNextSlide = () => {
        item.current[i].scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "nearest",
            inline: "center"
        })
    }
function scroll(direction) {
        if (direction === "left"){
            setCount(i - 1);
        }else{
            setCount(i + 1);
        }
        scrollToNextSlide();
    }
```

and return

```
<div className="slider">
                {slides.map((data, i) => (
                        <article className="art_class"
                                 key={i}
                                 ref={(ref) => (item.current[i] = ref)}>
                            <img className="art_img"
                                 src={data.img}/>
                            <header className="art_title">{data.title}</header>
                            <p>{data.subtitle}</p>
                        </article>
                    )
                )}
                <button>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faArrowLeft}
                        className="arrow left"
                        onClick={() => scroll("left") }>
                    </FontAwesomeIcon>
                </button>
                <button>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={faArrowRight}
                        className="arrow right"
                        onClick={() => scroll("right") }>
                    </FontAwesomeIcon>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, it was enough to assign the variable `let (something)` to const `i`
and replace it everywhere in the function **handleNavLeft** and **handleNavRight**